# Need to calculate field with special characters with ArcPy getting UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: arcpy, unicodeencodeerror

I wrote a script in ArcPy and it attributes the features in a shapefile with the name of the municipality it's located in but some of the municipalities have special characters, Conceição do Araguaia for example, and causes this error - UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6-7: ordinal not in range(128)

My code looks like this:

```
for muni in muni_list:
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(poly, "NEW_SELECTION", "{0} = {1}".format('Muni_ID', muni))
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(poly)
for row in cursor:
    print row.Muni_name
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(point, muni_field1, "{0}".format(row.Muni_name),"PYTHON_9.3","#")
```

The script runs fine until the last line of code is where the error occurs when it runs into "Conceição do Araguaia"

Comment: This more a generic Python issue. But first you should rewrite you code to use a Data Access Search cursor (`arcpy.da.SearchCursor`) and to begin the process of adapting to the process of Python3 (`print` will require parenthesis)

Comment: For such reasons my country adapted a coding system as well for neighborhoods, municipalities and provinces. Is that something you can fall back on as well?